# Hero image with overlapping text box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to have a hero image that has an overlapping text box but I'm struggling to get it to work the way I'd like. I can't get the hero height to match the size I want without changing the grid row height to a large number. I also can't get the text box to not cover up most of the image without doing another row height with a large number.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
.shell {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0 1fr 0;
  grid-template-rows: auto 8em 1fr auto;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .shell {
    grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr 20px;
  }
}

/* overlap */
.shell:before {
  content: "";
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.shell-header {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;

  color: #FFF;
  padding: 35px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 3; 
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow:  0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #FFF;
  max-width: 80rem;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="shell-header">

  </div>
  <div class="shell-body">

    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would go with the `flex` approach and `absolutely`-position the element you want to overlap in a `relatively`-positioned container.

```css
.shell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}


/* overlap */

.shell:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #FFF;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="shell-header"></div>
  <div class="shell-body">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! The flex is definitely easier to manipulate so thank you for recommending that!

Comment: How do you prevent any content from going behind the box over the banner with responsiveness in mind? Here is my code pen with text under the box instead of below. https://codepen.io/stormescape/pen/RwBMMzp

Comment: I asked a new question

Comment: @canijusttravel answered.